# DQL MySQL left join query sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables one called `Ratings` the other `Users`, ratings looks more or less like:

```
userid | depth | rating
1        0      5
1        3      8
1        4      9
```

How do I leftjoin *all* users to their ratings picking the smallest depth for each individual user?

Comment: What should the result be? In any case, I suspect this is just a variation of 'greatest n per group'.

Comment: What is expected output

Answer (score 0):

You have to left join the first table with the main id of other table and then you have to use aggregate function of mysql with element group by for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*, i.minDepth FROM
Users AS u LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT r.userId, min(r.depth) AS minDepth from Ratings AS r GROUP BY r.userId) AS i 
ON u.userId=i.userId;
```

Hope This Helps!